# Filter facebook events by gender with fql query

Tags: facebook-fql

There is a certain event that I want to filter by gender with an fql query. This is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT name, sex FROM friend WHERE sex IN 
(SELECT uid2 FROM eid WHERE uid1 = me()) AND sex = "male" LIMIT 10
```

Any suggestions?
it doesn't do the right thing I want this query to do,
I would like to filter invited members of an event by their gender.

Comment: there is a certain event that I want to filter by gender with fql query

Comment: SELECT name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN 
  (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND sex = "male" LIMIT 10

Comment: how can I re edit this query above to be able to filter a certain event I'm newbie sorry

Comment: I made the edits, but for future reference there is an "edit" button between "share" and "flag" at the bottom of the post. You might also want to mention what is going wrong with your above code.

Comment: I want this code to filter event members by their gender not filter on my friends. i'm really newbie to this..

Answer (score 0):

As of v2.0 API querying by gender depends on the users currently using the application. If the user isn't using the application, you will not be able to query the gender.